# Running a for-loop for the same function several times for a filtered dataframe, pythonic way to do that

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having an example pandas dataframe df:

```
TypeA TypeB timepoint value
A     AB     1         10
A     AB     2         10
A     AC     1         5
A     AC     2         15
A     AC     3         10
...
D     DB     1         1
D     DB     2         1
```

How can I run a function several times on a the unique combinations of 'TypeA' and 'TypeB' and store the results in a new dataframe, let's assume the following function, which is an example for many other functions I want to run on it:

```
import numpy as np
def running_mean(x, N):
    cumsum = np.cumsum(np.insert(x, 0, 0)) 
    return (cumsum[N:] - cumsum[:-N]) / float(N)
```

Right now, I do a `for-loop` but i think that is not a good idea, is there any python way to do that?

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df['typeA'].unique().tolist():
  df2 = df[df['typeA'] == i]
  for j in df2['typeB'].unique().tolist():
   df3 = df2[df2['typeB'] == j]
   moving_av = running_mean(df3['value'].values, 2)
   df3['moving_av'] = 0
   df3.iloc[1:1+len(moving_av), df3.columns.get_loc('moving_av')] = moving_av
   df4 = pd.concat([df4, df3])

df = pd.merge(df, df4, how='left', on=['typeA', 'Type', 'timepoint'])
```

my desired output is:

```
TypeA TypeB timepoint value moving_av
A     AB     1         10     0
A     AB     2         10     10
A     AC     1         5      0
A     AC     2         15     10
A     AC     3         10     12.5
...
D     DB     1         1      0
D     DB     2         1      1
```

Please note that the simple function is only a example, I am searching for a solution for a bigger function.

Comment: what is 'Wert'?

Comment: No, you need a loop. You can leverage `groupby` for that. Since you already have asked variations of this question multiple times, can you try to try read the documentation of `groupby` and avoid to manually loop over the indices?

Comment: i think there is no option to include  a manual function in groupby or?

Comment: Of course there is: `groupby.apply`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `groupby_transform` and use a rolling window:

```
df['moving_av'] = (df.groupby(['TypeA', 'TypeB'])['value']
                     .transform(lambda x: x.rolling(2).mean()).fillna(0))
print(df)

# Output
  TypeA TypeB  timepoint  value  moving_av
0     A    AB          1     10        0.0
1     A    AB          2     10       10.0
2     A    AC          1      5        0.0
3     A    AC          2     15       10.0
4     A    AC          3     10       12.5
5     D    DB          1      1        0.0
6     D    DB          2      1        1.0
```

Alternative:

```
df['moving_av'] = (df.groupby(['TypeA', 'TypeB'])
                     .rolling(2)['value'].mean().fillna(0)
                     .droplevel(['TypeA', 'TypeB']))
```